# UDP Socket Receive Function

Tags: swift, sockets, datagram

We have a server used UDP (datagram protocol) written in Java.

I was asked to develop an iOS app connect to it and receive data.

Today I connect it successful by CFSocket.

But I checked CFSocket reference which didn't find any receive function?

Answer (score -1):

UDP is a connection-less, unreliable, packet-oriented transport protocol. Receiving an UDP packet would be the same as starting a network service on your mobile device which listens to UDP packets. Most mobile devices do not provide services, they are clients only.

Long story short: You probably cant receive UDP packets in your iOS device, only send. The fastest workaround would be to change the transport protocol from UDP to TCP (also requires changing the server).

Comment: I am fairly sure that you can receive UDP packets on iOS devices.